# Subversion (using VisualSVN/Tortoise) refuses to pull down new files

Tags: svn, visualsvn, tortoisesvn

A problem has started occurring recently in which some new files added to the subversion repositories don't get pulled down to other clients after doing an Update.

If I browse the repository with Tortoise I can see the file. I can then right click on it and select 'Update to revision', which will pull the file down to the client. Unfortunately this is very time consuming as there is no way to pull down all files in a folder - i.e. I have to do this for each file individually.

The weird thing is, it doesn't occur with all files and it is not occurring on all client machines. I have tried totally deleting the working folder and pulling it all down again but the problem persists.

I am using the latest versions of Tortoise and VisualSVN.

Anyone else seen something like this?

Comment: I have had 2 similar problems. At least one of the files was not even a new file (it was a couple months old). I did a get on the grand-parent directory multiple times and the file would not update (I didn't even realize it needed to update)

When I manually went to the file and updated just that file though, it updated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Known bug](http://groups.google.com/group/tortoisesvn-dev/browse_thread/thread/b3f6f04feac7f8e0) in <strike>Tortoise</strike>SVN 1.6.1: if you add an empty folder, the folder depth in your working copy will be restricted to "empty". You can work around this by updating once with the "update to revision..." dialog and selecting "fully recursive" as depth.

This has been fixed in 1.6.2.

**edit**: note that TortoiseSVN uses the SVN client library, which is where the bug was. The command line client had the same problem.

Comment: Thanks, the workaround does work. This seems to be the most likely culprit although I have 1.6.2 installed and it is still occurring.

Comment: @jorgeburgos: Once the folder depth has been set to "empty" by 1.6.1, you need to do a fully recursive update. Upgrading to 1.6.2 prevents the problem in the future but cannot fix existing instances of it.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I can think of is maybe it has to do with the 1.5 to 1.6 transition? Make sure everyone has a 1.6-based version of tortoiseSVN and try again perhaps.

Also, the way you are phrasing the question makes it sound like you are using SVN for distribution of files instead of concurrency. If that is the case, consider a tool like Unison instead of SVN.

Comment: Thanks - yes it quite possibly did occur during the transition to 1.6, but I am already using the latest version of Tortoise which supports 1.6.
You are also perceptive - I do use SVN for distribution of files. I am the soul developer at the moment and it doesnt really bother me but I will check out Unison anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just happen to have the same problem. Here is a solution :

```
svn update `svn ls`
```

Yes, I know this problem is far from now, but it still comes up high in web search.