# Subversion not updating working copy properly

Tags: svn

Over the weekend, another programmer added a file to a project and committed it to the repository.  Today, I run an update on the repo and the file does not get pulled down to my working copy.

I was able to delete the directory and run an update to get all the files from the directory again, but that concerns me that certain files were not being brought down from the repo.

Any ideas on why this was happening?  I was using the HEAD revision and this directory was at the correct revision number.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866835/subversion-using-visualsvn-tortoise-refuses-to-pull-down-new-files

Comment: It may be related, but this folder was not empty (as stated in the question you linked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository is probably checked out without "Fully recursive" and it only updates the working copy.

You could've tried to do a "Update to revision" function, and specify that the update depth should be fully recursive.