# SVN Weirdness Day 2: SVN List and SVN Update Report Different Things

Tags: svn, svn-update

In a subdirectory of my svn working copy, I do

```
svn list
```

I see that there are 6 files in the repository (same as I see with SVNX). Nice. But in my working copy, there are two files, which are from some historical point that I do not remember. So I do

```
svn update
```

and it says that all files are up to date to revision 122 (which is the head revision). **How can there be a difference between doing an update and a list?** More importantly, how can I get those files back without doing a fresh checkout?

I know that the answer will either reveal that I'm a complete newbie OR that svn is a terrible kludge. Personally, I just want to get back to work.

**Edit:** `svn cleanup` does nothing at all, and `svn status` reports nothing at all.

**Edit:** Here's exactly what I did, since one of the commenters asked.

```
root@Dans-13:/dans-data/php/nasa-secrets-revealed/trunk/images/testmenu$svn update
At revision 122.
root@Dans-13:/dans-data/php/nasa-secrets-revealed/trunk/images/testmenu$svn list
graph-big0.gif
graph-big1.gif
graph-big2.gif
graph0.gif
graph1.gif
graph2.gif
root@Dans-13:/dans-data/php/nasa-secrets-revealed/trunk/images/testmenu$ls
.svn        graph-big0.gif  graph0.gif
```

Comment: Can you post the listings and exact commands you ran?

Comment: This is also happening to me. What client and server versions are you using? Mine is 1.6.5 on the client and 1.4.4 on the server.

Comment: tuler, check my answer below.. I don't know what client I was running back in May. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have a [sparse checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html). Try

```
svn update --depth infinity --set-depth infinity
```

Comment: Yeah, but since I did the original checkout myself, I know that's not the case. I'll upvote you because my problem is with svn, not with helpful SO people.

Comment: a simple 'svn st -v' should show you whether you have a sparse checkout or not.

Comment: so you're saying that even if I didn't DO a sparse checkout myself, it could happen accidentally?

Comment: That depends on your knowledge of svn - you might not have intended to do it but still done it.

Comment: What? I never use --depth nor --set-depth. Is it still possible?

Comment: If you *really* never use --depth, then no. But just run 'svn st -v' or 'svn info' on the folder and check. It takes a second to check that, much less than arguing here over and over.

Comment: Sorry Stefan, I never saw your comment until now (months later). .The reason that I didn't follow your advice was that I had resolved the problem and could NOT check with svn st -v. So my question was academic. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a `svn:ignore` property set up in the directory?

```
svn pg svn:ignore .
```

Comment: No. Just ran svn status --no-ignore and there are no files listed.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know of SVN, this is completely impossible and should not happen.

Eventually I ended up doing this: **Delete the entire directory from level up and run `svn update`**. Sometimes, the answer is to walk *around* the problem.

Comment: As I said in the question, I ran svn cleanup as well. Thanks!

Comment: This is equivalent to Stefan's answer. You probably encountered this known bug which causes unintended sparse working copies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866835/subversion-using-visualsvn-tortoise-refuses-to-pull-down-new-files/867839#867839

Comment: @wcoenen, thank you for your comment. The problem is really the time spent figuring out which directory was pointing to a different revision... there was no indication of this with svn info, nor svn list nor anything. Although debugging is fun, I'd prefer to debug when the code is wrong... is there any way to assure a good switch?

Comment: Also, I might mention that it's impossible that I experienced a tortoise bug since I'm using command-line svn in osx. I wish I had Tortoise :)

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe you have done svn switch or svn update -r X in that working copy folder. The output from svn:info could tell you that.

Comment: Thanks. svn info revealed that I was pointing to the right place in the repository, and svn update revealed that I was updating to the right rev.