# SVN Won't download newly added files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

SVN won't download newly added files but will update existing.  Developer B adds 3 new files to the repo, and when Developer A updates it does not download the files.  Both using TortoiseSVN and VisualSVN.  Does anyone know what could be causing this problem?  If Developer A goes to the Repo Browser they can see them, but it just won't update their folder with them on an Update.  Help would be appreciated.

Comment: This bug is still there in Tortoise SVN 1.14.0 64 bit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From this answer:
[Subversion (using VisualSVN/Tortoise) refuses to pull down new files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866835/subversion-using-visualsvn-tortoise-refuses-to-pull-down-new-files/867839#867839)

Call once the "**update to revision...**" dialog and select "**fully recursive**" as depth.
There seems to be a problem with empty folders.

Comment: This worked.  It's strange because it was not an empty folder, it was simple a couple of files added to an existing folder that already contained a dozen other files.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: This fix works! This bug is still there in Tortoise SVN 1.14.0 64 bit

Answer (score -1):

Is there any chance the developer did the initial checkout using [sparse directories](http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/notes/sparse-directories.txt)? Also make sure they aren't passing an incorrect `--depth` parameter to the update command.