# How to get all changes with an svn update, using TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

TortoiseSVN seems to fail to update my working copy when I issue an update command.  If I do an update to revision and make sure that fully recursive is selected, then it picks up the changes.  Additionally, when I checked out the copy from SVN, fully recursive was selected.

How can I get a normal update to pickup all of the changes?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866835/subversion-using-visualsvn-tortoise-refuses-to-pull-down-new-files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was due to the bug with 1.6.2 - Upgrading to 1.6.3 seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

By default, subversion will not clobber your local changes when you do a normal update -- that is by design.  With tortoiseSVN, the best thing to do is "check for modifications" before or after an update.  If you don't want your changes, you can do a "revert" before or after the update.