# How to fix "containing working copy admin area is missing" in SVN?

Tags: svn, repair, delete-directory

I deleted manually a directory I just added, offline, in my repository. I can't restore the directory.

Any attempt to do an update or a commit will fail with:

```
"blabla/.svn" containing working copy admin area is missing.
```

I understand why, but is there anyway to fix this.

I don't want to checkout the entire repo and add my changes to it manually, it would take hours.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

According to this: http://www.devcha.com/2008/03/svn-directory-svn-containing-working.html

Check-out the folder "blabla" to a different location and then copy its .svn folder back into the original "blabla".

Comment: I have SVN so much. Littering `.svn` subdirectories all over the place must have been the worst idea in version control history.

Comment: Folks, do check out the below suggestions by Rob, it's far easy then the current solution.

Comment: Mohammed, thanks for the heads up. That worked for me. Was trying to get SVN to ignore a log directory, and deleting .svn got me to this problem. Rob's solution solved it.

Comment: Johannes, i am not a proponent of SVN either but the advantage of the .svn directories is that you can check out sub directories of a repository and maintain version control.

Comment: @MohammadArif, There are two "Robs" now

Comment: @CharlesClayton, I meant Rob Wells now :)

Answer (score 123):

fwiw, I had a similar situation and used **svn --force delete __dir__**. That solved the issue for me. Then i continued working with my working copy as normal.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Updates and cleans failed because the directory never was in the repository, but the working copy was sure that it was under revision control. I wonder if I added the directory, but then deleted it before I committed it?

Comment: This is very good. I had added a directory, deleted the .svn but never commited. This totaly did the trick

Comment: Thank you; this answer saved me a lot of time. `svn cleanup` then `svn --force delete <directory-that-doesn't-exist-but-should>` worked for me.

Comment: Worked on the second try, I first tried without --force, that somehow left a lock file in .svn of the parent which I had to manually remove. Second time with --force fixed the problem.

Comment: Thank you.  This totally did the trick.  Force the delete and then add back the directory did it for me.

Comment: Hm, that command simply gives me the same "working copy" error.

Answer (score 73):

What I did to fix this was to delete the *local* copy of the folder under question and then do an `svn update` of the parent directly afterwards.

Fixed it right up.

Comment: I can't believe...I tried everything...and it was just that easy!!! It perfectly worked, many thanks!!!!!

Comment: This is the most straight forward answer.

Answer (score 35):

Can you try to check out a new copy of the parent directory?

**Edit:** To be bit more specific, I meant to suggest going up one level and deleting the containing directory. Then do a

```
svn update --set-depth infinity
```

to replace the directory.

Comment: I tried that but for some strange reason, I end up with an empty directory. I don't get it...

Comment: An explicit <code>svn update blabla</code> from the parent should work too.

Comment: @jmanning2k, that's what i thought as well, but the OP said that he'd tried it and it hadn't worked.

Comment: To clarify, I suggested `--set-depth infinity` because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866835/subversion-using-visualsvn-tortoise-refuses-to-pull-down-new-files/

Comment: Awesome, it's resolved the issue, I think, it should be the accepted answer because one doesn't need to take the checkout and copy the .svn folder.

Comment: This needs so much more upvotes... quick and relatively (for svn standards) clean solution.

Answer (score 6):

I added a directory to svn, then I accidentally deleted the .svn folder within.

I used

```
svn delete --keep-local folderName
```

to fix my problem.

Comment: This worked for me when my IDE added a directory, and then I had moved a directory of the same name into place before it was committed.

Comment: tried this, but still couldn't commit. I used `svn checkout --force [url]` which recreated the .svn folder

Answer (score 4):

I just did 'svn revert /blabla' and it worked, the folder is back and I can svn delete it

Comment: Thanks. I had this issue and tried your suggestion and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

The error "Directory 'blah/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing" occurred when I attempted to add the directory to the repository, but did not have enough filesystem privileges to do so. The directory was not already in the repository, but it was claiming to be under version control after the failed add.

Checking out a copy of the parent directory to another location, and replacing the .svn folder in the parent dir of the working copy allowed me to add and commit the new directory successfully (after fixing the file permissions, of course).

Answer (score 2):

We use maven and svn. It was an mistaken checkin of target directory to SVN that cause this error. Removing that fixed everything, if this hint helps anyone.

Comment: Removing what/from where exacly?

Comment: maven creates the "target" directory, when building. Usually no one is suppose to check in this one. An accedent checkin made a permission issue next time checkout which created this error. Removing "target" directory from SVN solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I tried `svn rm --force /path/to/dir` to no avail but ended up just running `svn up` and it fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error recently, when the files were excluded by settings in my SVN globals. The error was especially nasty since I also deleted the files directly from the repository - and this meant that the above solutions were refusing wouldn't work. In this case, manually deleting the .svn directory from the directory that I removed from SVN allowed me to run an update which then allowed me to commit.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, when I was trying to switch "C:\superfolder"

Error messages:

> ```
> Directory 'C:\superfolder\subfolder\.svn'
> containing
> working copy admin area is missing
> Please execute the 'Cleanup' command.
> ```

After trying to do a "cleanup", I got the following error:

> ```
>  Cleanup failed to process the following paths:
>  C:\superfolder\
> 'C:\superfolder\subfolder\' is not a working copy directory
> ```

**Solution:**

1. Delete the folder  "subfolder"
2. Clean up the folder "superfolder"
3. Try to switch again the folder "superfolder"

this worked for me.
Please let me know if it also works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error recently. It was caused by root owning a couple of files in the directory giving this error.

After I changed the permissions everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't understand much from your posts.
My solution is

1. Cut the problematic folder and copy to some location.
2. Do Get Solution From Subversion into another working directory (just new one).
3. Add your saved folder to the new working copy and add it As Existing Project (if it's project as in my case).
4. Commit;

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. Just move blabla to another location temporarily, tell svn to revert it, and then move it back. It is treated as a new addition. Simple!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest that helped me:

```
rm -rf _dir_in_question_
svn up
```

If you have changes in the problematic dir, then this is not a good solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem when replacing a third party API library with a newer version, and none of the solutions here really worked for me because I wanted to replace the SVN version with the local version.  My solution was as follows:

1) Move the offending folder to my home dir, delete it from SVN and commit:

```
mv foldercausingproblem ~/
svn --force delete foldercausingproblem
svn commit --message "Temporary removing folder with old API"
```

2) Put the folder back, add it to SVN and commit again:

```
mv ~/foldercausingproblem ./
svn --force add .
svn commit --message "Finally all working!"
```

Slightly irritating to have to commit twice, but it seems to have worked fine.

Comment: I generally like to work on code separately from my working copy of the repo (IDEs, compilers, error parsers etc. do not like .svn, and there is no 'EVERYONE IGNORE .SVNs EXCEPT SVN!' command in Eclipse afaik); this means that the basic SVN commit process for me is: 1. checkout working copy of repo 2. delete root directory of project I have an update for 3. copy and paste updated project directory to parent directory of project in working copy 4. svn add --force <projname> 5. commit.  This usually works, but can occasionally throw the OP's error. Jamie Brown's fix worked in my case

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone wants yet another solution:

1. Check in your new folder as "foldername2"
2. Go into Tortise SVN repo browser
3. Rename "foldername2" to "foldername"
4. In windows explorer do an update

Hope it helps someone.

-Ev

Answer (score 0):

First of all checkout the project into your system in a folder. Then remove the .svn folder from conflict project and copy the .svn folder from new checkout folder and paste into your working copy folder. Then problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the same issue happened when I both:

- deleted (`--force`) a .map file
- added *.map to `svn:ignore` via `svn propedit svn:ignore .`

My solution was to:

1. undo changes to the property
2. commit changes to the files
3. checkout a fresh copy of the repository (alas!)
4. change the property and commit

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was trying to add a directory to svn. I solved it by going into repo browser. Right clicking in the left window, choosing add folder and adding the directory directly in the repo browser.

I then deleted the directory locally (after backup of course) did a clean up and svn update and everything was working again.

Comment: I might add that this is added to my "svn sucks" file.

Answer (score 0):

A common task I experienced was having to take one repo directory in staging and copy it to another repo - both under SVN and both called the same name.  The way that worked for me was the following:

```
svn --force delete PROBLEMATIC-DIR
svn export "https://OLD REPO-A/ new-repo-A"
svn add new-repo-A
svn commit new-repo-A
```