# What can I do about the "Working copy not locked; this is probably a bug, please report" SVN error?

Tags: xcode, svn

I am trying to commit my entire project to Subversion, and I get the following error message after clicking `SCM > Commit Entire Project`:

> Error: 155005 (Working copy not locked; this is probably a bug, please report) Description: Commit failed (details follow):
>   Error: 155005 (Working copy not locked; this is probably a bug, please report) Description: Directory '/SubVersion/SplitView/trunk/SplitView/build/SplitView.build/SplitView.pbxindex/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing

Does anyone know how to fix this bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this article](http://www.devcha.com/2008/03/svn-directory-svn-containing-working.html). You've deleted your .svn directory.

Comment: Also: this question is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394076/how-to-fix-containing-working-copy-admin-area-is-missing-in-svn).