# Subversion sometimes doesn't see new files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Sometimes when a team member adds a file to a subversion repository it doesn't get updated in the other team members working copies (once they request an update). We have to copy the files from the repo browser to the working copy, delete them in the repository and then re-commit them in order for it to work properly.

It happens randomly and with different team members so I am unable to figure out what the issue might be.

We all use TortoiseSVN and VisualSVN for the server. Does anybody have any ideas as to what might be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are using some net filesystem introducing delay or caching writes.

A network issue IMHO.

EDIT:

After further infos from the answerer I think the issue can be different.

**Try to call the "update to revision..." dialog and select "fully recursive" as depth.**

It should be something related to recursive adds, or add into newly created folders not already committed.

It was suggested in [Subversion (using VisualSVN/Tortoise) refuses to pull down new files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866835/subversion-using-visualsvn-tortoise-refuses-to-pull-down-new-files/867839#867839)

Comment: Wouldn't it then "fix" itself once the caching write is finished? This is a problem that persists of multiple revisions.

Comment: It is possible the SVN client is somehow wrongly handling the net fs caching/problem. Have you tried to use a different client?

Comment: Is it related to the following 3d: _http://serverfault.com/questions/33973/tortoisesvn-missing-file-in-update_ ?

Comment: It is exactly the same problem.